# Unable to set SQL Execution Advanced Options

Tags: sql-server, settings, execution, sql-server-2016

After installing the latest version of SQL Server 2016 (16.3), I've noticed none of my users can set the Transaction Isolation Level or Deadlock Priority under Options->SQL Execution->SQL Server->Advanced.

If you see the image below, both drop downs are technically there but squashed so far left that you can click on them or view anything really.

This is all on a Windows 10 x64 box (Non-Anniversary Edition). I've tested this on a clean box that has never had SQL Server 2016 and got the same results.

I have a feeling this may be a bug in the latest version but I cannot find any other threads about it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the window is resizable, can you uncover them by dragging that bottom right corner out farther? You can always `SET` these options in the query itself as a workaround.

Comment: what is the ssms version you are using

Comment: No, Resizing does not work even with it Fullscreen in size. We are having them set it each time they run a Query but there are a few who are forgetful minded which is the reason why.
I'm using SSMS version 13.0.15700.28

Comment: My question is why do you have "users" using SSMS in the first place? This is not a tool that should be used by people not paying attention to detail.

Comment: They have Read Only access to the Tables and they use it to troubleshoot DB issues with our software program. If they see a problem either with the way the software saves to the DB or data being read from it, they report it so my DEV Teams can fix it ASAP. Even though they have Read Access, I don't want them them causing blocking when they run a Query (especially a complex one).

Comment: I can replicate this behaviour using SSMS 16.3 on Windows 10 Pro x64 - it looks like a UI bug. You'll probably have to revert to an earlier version.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in the new SSMS release, 16.4.1 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx